# node js request proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

I send a request through a proxy and always receive such a response

```
tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET
```

or

```
tunneling socket could not be established, cause= socket hang up
```

My code

```
      let settings = {
    url: `url`,
    headers: {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    proxy: `http://${ip}:${port}`,
    strictSSL: false
  }
request.request(settings, (err, response, body) => {
 // err here
})
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Now this error : Error: Tunnel creation failed. Socket error: Error: read ECONNRESET

My code:

```
  const request = require('request'),
  proxyingAgent = require('proxying-agent');
```

;

```
let settings = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    // proxy: `http://${obj.proxy[obj.proxyIdx]}`,
    agent: proxyingAgent.create(`http://${obj.proxy[obj.proxyIdx]}`, url),
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

About your code, problem possibly lies in your `settings` object. 

You need to use syntax like this:

```
let settings = {
  url,
  headers: {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
  },
  method: 'POST',
  proxy: `http://${ip}:${port}`,
  strictSSL: false
}
```

Here we use ES6 to make object short.
But also, you can establish proxy connection with npm package [proxying agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxying-agent).
Your code should look something like this:

```
const proxyingAgent = require('proxying-agent');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const host = <your host>;
const port = <port>;

const creds = {
  login: 'username',
  password: 'pass'
};

const port = <proxy port>;

const buildProxy = (url) => {
  return {
      agent: proxyingAgent.create(`http://${creds.login}:${creds.password}@${host}:${port}`, url)
  };
};

//If you don't have credentials for proxy, you can rewrite function

const buildProxyWithoutCreds = (url) => {
  return {
      agent: proxyingAgent.create(`http://${host}:${port}`, url)
  };
};
```

And than you can use it with your url and credentials. We'll use [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) package.

```
const proxyGetData = async (url, type) => {
   try {
       const proxyData = buildProxyWithoutCreds(url);
       // Make request with proxy. Here we use promise based library node-fetch
       let req = await fetch(url, proxyData);

       if (req.status === 200) {
         return await req[type]();
       }
       return false;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(`Error during request: ${e.message}`);
    }
  };
```

Comment: @Inomezi I guess problem lies in authentication to your proxy. ECONNRESET error means connection error. ECONNRESET means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. So, my advice to check if you need some credentials like username/password to access your proxy.